# Cannot use microsoft.visualstudio.com/<team name here> in the Auto Issue Filer

Tags: accessibility-insights

I am trying to file issues automatically via the automatic issue filer. Using my Azure Boards project URL which is `https://microsoft.visualstudio.com/<my team board name here>`.

I get a server error:

> Server error - Invalid argument value. Parameter name: typeNames

Answer (score 0):

I'm a software engineer on the accessibility insights team. This looks like a bug in our issue filing code. We make some assumptions about the types of work items available on the ADO project, so issue filing will fail if the types are not valid. In this case, we're trying to create an "Issue" work item, but that isn't a valid work item type for your project.

I've opened [a bug in our github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-web/issues/3874), which our team will triage and decide how to handle. As a possible workaround in the meantime, you could try configuring issue filing to use the "repro steps" field instead of "description". This will create a Bug instead of an Issue, so it should succeed if your project allows Bug work items.

Edit: As noted in the github issue, we have received similar issues before, which we resolved by noting the bug/issue distinction in our [documentation](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/web/getstarted/issuefiling/#configure-your-issue-filing-service). Could you let us know if this (and using the "repro steps" option) unblocks you in your use case?

Comment: Using repro steps fails as well. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I expected that most ADO projects would allow Bug work items. What work item type do you use to track bugs/issues?

Comment: I'm also curious how work items are configured in your project. At project settings > overview > process, is there a "Bug" or Issue" type that has been disabled, or do those types not exist at all? If they're disabled, you could try enabling them and checking issue filing again.